# AttributeError:: 'module' object has no attribute 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror

The code for the error in title is below. I googled several times but could find out what the reasons are:

```
class MyLinearModel(Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyLinearModel, self).__init__()
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name="dense1")

def call(self, x):
    x = self.flatten(x)
    return self.d1(x)

model = MyLinearModel()

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()

...
```

and I got the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy'
```

Comment: What is the output of `tf.__version__`?

Comment: tf.__version__ is 1.12.0

Comment: You will need to upgrade tensorflow to use this. Either to 1.15 or 2.x.

Comment: if I cannot upgrade to tensorflow2, is there an equivalent for in tensorflow1 for SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oldest version i could find that has a similar function is 1.13, here is the link https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.13/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy.md

It does require the one-hot encoded targets instead of passing in just integers representing the indices.

You will find the same function you are looking for in Tensorflow 1.15.0, here is a link to the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

Both versions require CUDA 10.0 if you are planing on using the GPU version though.

Here is a link to the docs for tensorflow-gpu installation https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#install_cuda_with_apt

Just as a side note, when ever you would like to see what are the contents of a certain module in python, just call the built-in help() funciton on it. In your case you could do help(tf.keras.losses), for the most part, it might offer some insights.